# Run sudo apt-get install without internet connection

Tags: python, linux, ftp, raspberry-pi, apt

My end goal is to turn my Raspberry Pi into a FTP Server. It is connected to the network, but with no internet connection. It seems like this would be extremely easy to accomplish if I could just run the "sudo apt-get install ...." command, but since I have no internet this is not possible.

I downloaded the "ftplib" for python which I think will allow me to connect to and interact with my FTP server once I get it up, but right now I am stuck.

I do not know to much about Linux, or web servers so thank you for your patience in advance.

I think a possible solution would be to download a LAMP package on my computer with internet and then transfer it over to the Raspberry Pi, but I am not sure what kind of path and folder issues I might run into then.

Comment: What Linux distro you're using?

Comment: You should accept the answer that helps you the most.  That way you at least support the community that supports you.

Comment: Hey guys, it was my first question on stack overflow and I was expecting an email when I got an answer which I apparently set up wrong so I didn't see any activity until just now, sorry about leaving everybody hanging for a bit. I am using 2.7 now

Comment: Actually my distro is Raspbian “wheezy”, 2.7 is my python version haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing this is never ever clean, and never perfect.  But below is what I've done to get it to work at times.

You will need a machine that is similar to the FTP server and from the FTP server you will need to download all packages and dependencies.  Typically, from the internet machine you will first run:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

The above command cleans the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory so that you can ensure it only contains the package and dependencies you desire.  Then execute:

```
sudo apt-get -d build-dep <package_name>
```

The `-d` does a download only and `build-dep` gets all the dependencies required and drops them into `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.  This is why you at least need a similar build.  Sometimes you may even need to do a `sudo apt-get remove <package name>` if your machine already has the package that your destination server requires.

You then take the data out of that directory and put it on some device to transfer to your FTP server.  From there you execute on your target machine:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

The other thing you can do is use apt offline http://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org/

Comment: I think I forgot to mention something important, that my internet machine is Windows 7, and I don't readily have access to a linux system now, but in the future, it sounds like the way to go would be to have a friend with linux connected to the internet download a copy for me and do all the compiling, and then it should be good to go I think, also the last link you sent looks pretty helpful!

Comment: @Shaun314 good luck!  Doing it this way sucks, but hopefully this info helps you out.

Comment: If you know all the packages and dependencies you need, you can use `apt-get download ...` to download the deb's into the current directory, saving the need to `apt-get clean` and all.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to download the packages **and** it's dependencies. Then place them on the sd card and execute:

```
cd folder_with_debs
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Btw, it would be easier in most cases to plug an eth cable into the raspberry pi for short (As you are posting here on SO, you should have access to the internet in general)

Comment: That Would be very nice, but let's just say due to all kinds of fun corporate internet policy things, that is much easier said than done. And I am also on a Windows machine with internet now. Thank you so much for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

This is a really long comment in response to @Inquisitor.

Super helpful answer, by the way; it got me on the right track. I'm going to include a few notes below for anyone interested; please note that all this runaround ended up not working, and I just downloaded the files directly from:

```
ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tk8.5/
ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tcl8.5/
```

But hopefully this will be useful to someone.

I'm installing tk8.5-dev and tcl8.5-dev on the pi. To do this I found:

```
https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armhf/tk8.5-dev/download
https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/armhf/tcl8.5-dev/download
```

I added the repo (`deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main`) to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then ran `sudo apt-get update`. On update, it yelled at me with:

```
GPG error: http://ftp.de.debian.org wheezy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 6FB2A1C265FFB764
```

because I'm not on debian, but I did

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6FB2A1C265FFB764
```

It told me `no ultimately trusted keys found`. I ran `sudo apt-get update` again. If you miss a key (like I did originally), it'll tell you `There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 6FB2A1C265FFB764`. If you still have problems, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Authentication%20Tab) might be helpful, or maybe the --allow-unauthenticated flag.

At this point, I ran

```
sudo apt-get -d build-dep tk8.5-dev_8.5.11-2_armhf.deb tcl8.5-dev_8.5.11-2_armhf.deb
```

and got

```
Unable to find a source package for tk8.5-dev_8.5.11-2_armhf.deb
```

So I [added an architecture](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) to dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
```

And apt-get still wasn't able to find the packages. Sooo I gave up and downloaded the files directly. In my case, since I couldn't use build-dep, I downloaded and installed everything listed here for armhf:

```
https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/libxss-dev
https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/libxft-dev
https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/tk8.5-dev
https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/tk8.5
https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/tcl8.5-dev
https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/tcl8.5
```

There are more dependencies, so I'll work through those today and edit this answer if I find anything else interesting.

Of course, all good things are [chiastic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiastic_structure), so I had to undo everything again, since I don't want to install debian armhf packages on my amd64 mint system:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
sudo apt-key del 8B48AD6246925553
sudo apt-key del 6FB2A1C265FFB764
sudo apt-get update
```

And removed `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main` from /etc/apt/sources.list

More sources:
http://savvyadmin.com/download-pgp-keys-with-apt-key/

Anyway, I don't know if this counts as an answer, but hopefully it'll be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg -i ftplib
```

for a Debian package.

Answer (score 0):

### The proper way to do it: `apt-offline`

The real good way of installing packages on an offline system is to use `apt-offline`. It as really few dependencies allowing you to install it on the offline system with `dpkg -i`.
Download the deb file on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=apt-offline).

#### Example

```sh
# Online is the computer connected to internet
# Offline is the computer disconnected from internet
# ---
# ## Install apt-offline ## 
# Online
apt update
apt install apt-offline
# Offline
#   Download last package from pkgs.org
dpkg -i apt-offline_1.8.*_all.deb


# ## Update System ##
# Offline
apt-offline set --update updates.sig
# Online
apt-offline get updates.sig --bundle updates.zip
# Offline 
apt-offline install updates.zip


# ## Upgrade System ##
# <!> Update must be done before.
# Offline
apt-offline set --upgrade upgrade.sig
# Online
apt-offline get upgrade.sig --bundle upgrades.zip
# Offline 
apt-offline install upgrades.zip
apt upgrade --no-download --fix-missing


# ## Install packages##
# <!> Update must be done before.
# pkg1, pkg2 & pkg3 being the packages you want to install
# Offline 
apt-offline set install.sig --install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
# Online
apt-offline get install.sig --bundle install.zip
# Offline 
apt-offline install install.zip
apt install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 --no-download --fix-missing
```

**Important**: Do not proceed to the update and upgrade/install at the same time. By doing so the upgrade is performed from the package list already installed on the computer, not after the update.

**Important 2**: `apt-offline install` and `upgrade` are not enough to get the packages installed. The only thing this command do, is to fill up the cache of apt (`/var/cache/apt/archives`) with the packages. That allows you to proceed with `apt install --no-download --fix-missing`.